# In ipad devices chrome browser, Page URL is displayed instead of page title in browser tab

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, google-chrome, web

In my web project, page URL is displayed in browser tab title in iPad devices chrome browser. This is my issue. This issue is not getting reproduced if we reload the page(i.e., page title is displayed). I am getting this issue on page navigation. I have checked other sites(Example:Google), this issue is getting reproduced. I am getting the same issue on page navigation in Google site. I think, this is an open issue. If this is an open issue, please provide me valid link for the open issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not third-party technical support. I suggest you search the Chromium bug database.

Comment: @Barmar. I have searched but I am not able to find this is an open issue. Can you please provide me link that it is a known issue.

Comment: No, I can't. I have no idea if this is a known issue, I would just have to search the bug database. Why don't you submit it yourself? If the developers recognize it as a known bug, they'll link your report to the existing entry.